# quitar cuadro explicacion funcion vsc

Tags: vscode

Quería preguntarles cómo solucionar el problema de que, cada vez que escribo un método en VSCode, me aparece la explicación del mismo y tengo que presionar esc para que se vaya. Es muy molesto, ¿alguien sabe cómo descativar esa función?

[Me refiero a esto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebTen.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Código>Preferencias>Ajustes (Mac)
Archivo>Preferencias>Ajustes(Windows)

Tienes que buscar editor.hover.enable y deshabilitar el checkbox.

Fuente: https://www.kindacode.com/article/vs-code-how-to-disable-enable-suggestions-on-hover/ (Hay video demo en el link)

Comment: muchisimas gracias!!!!funciono perfecto